# Make JSplitPane fully transparent

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jtree, jsplitpane

I am writing GUI program in Java.

I have a `JPanel` called `jpanel1` that I inserted a `JSplitpane` (`jSplitPane1`) on it. I set right and left components of `jSplitPane1`; `jpanel2` & `jpanel3`. I set a background image on downward panel (`jpanel1`) and I want to `JSplitPane` and it's right and left components be transparent such that I can see the background image on them. Is this possible in Java?  If this is possible can I use that method to transparent `JTree` as `JSplitpane`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of your best attempt (so we can play with it & test solutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the L&F. AquaL&F on MacOS will respect setOpaque(false) but e.g. Nimbus does not seem to care about it. To force a transparent divider you need to override it in the UI definition of the JSplitPane

```
 jSplitPane.setUI(new BasicSplitPaneUI(){
            @Override
            public BasicSplitPaneDivider createDefaultDivider() {
                return new BasicSplitPaneDivider(this){
                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics g) {
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

A potential disadvantage is that this approach overrides the L&F for this component and thus might take away other L&F theming elements.

Comment: I asked this question several years ago but your approach may be effective. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to call: `setOpaque(boolean)`.

Comment: I tested before but not effective!

Comment: +1, works fine for me. Since the poster hasn't posted an SSCCE I guess we can't offer any more help.